# GAE Python AssertionError: write() argument must be string

Tags: html, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I am using Sublime Text 2 as my editor and creating a new Google App Engine project.

EDIT:  I am running this code through localhost.   I get this error on when viewing the app on appspot:
    `Status: 500 Internal Server Error Content-Type: text/plain Content-Length: 59 A server error occurred. Please contact the administrator.`

I have this code:

```
import webapp2 as webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

class IndexPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write('Hello, World!')

app = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/.*', IndexPage)], debug = True)

def main():
    run_wsgi_app(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It causes an AssertionError:

> File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 202, in write
>
> assert type(data) is StringType,"write() argument must be string"
>
> AssertionError: write() argument must be string

What does the error mean and what could be causing it?

Comment: Are you using the python 2.7 runtime? `run_wsgi_app()` isn't normally used anymore.

Comment: @Wooble Yes I'm using python 2.7; `run_wsgi_app()` is what I normally use.  What is the correct way?

Comment: You generally just set the `app` variable and set `app.yaml` to use it as a WSGI application.

Comment: @Wooble If I change the end of my code to this:
`app = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', IndexPage)], debug = True)`

And add to YAML:
`- url: /.*
  script: index.app`

It still gives the same error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8558323/error-in-deployed-gae-requesthandler-using-webapp2 looks like a similar problem, except that in your case you're providing a string literal, not a template rendered as a `unicode`, so the error message makes no sense here.

Comment: @Wooble Exactly, I saw that post before I asked the question.  I have created a number of GAE apps before and this is the first time I've had this issue.  I am wondering if it is a encoding issue with my .yaml or .py files, but I am lost on this one

Comment: Could be; I can't reproduce this on my machine copying your source exactly.

Comment: Did you have something other than 'Hello World' at some point? Do you still get a problem if you stop the server and re-start it? Some older versions of the dev_appserver had problems reloading files after you made changes... and there aren't 202 lines in the code you've provided.

Comment: @Greg The line 202 is from the handlers.py, which is a GAE thing

Comment: I fixed the problem.  GAE wasn't properly reading my YAML file.  When I clicked "Edit" within the GAE GUI it was displaying the wrong version of the app.yaml.  It is working now, thanks everyone.  I knew it was something quirky like that.

Comment: What 'GAE GUI' are you using here?

Comment: The official GAE app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GAE was not recognizing my app.yaml file properly.  Once I fixed that, it worked.  Thanks