# Python & GAE - StringType write() argument type parsing

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine-python

When running `dev_appserver.py .`, I get the following error when trying to access `http://localhost:8080`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 86, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 128, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions 2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 204, in write
    assert type(data) is StringType,"write() argument must be string"
AssertionError: write() argument must be string
```

I've searched and it seems to come back to my app.yaml file, per these links:

- [SO Question for GAE Assertion Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744694/gae-python-assertionerror-write-argument-must-be-string)
- [Russian Question site with
  same information](http://qaru.site/questions/7300279/gae-python-assertionerror-write-argument-must-be-string)

I'm just not sure how to go about debugging it. Below is my app.yaml file and my main.py file. I'm super new to the GAE platform and any help would be appreciated.

app.yaml file:

```
application: gqtimer
version: 1-56
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: false

handlers:
- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: static/images/favicon.ico
  upload: static/images/favicon.ico

- url: /_ah/login_required
  script: main.py

- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /player.*
  script: main.py
  login: required

- url: /stat.*
  script: main.py
  login: required

- url: .*
  script: main.py

libraries:
- name: django
  version: "1.11"
```

main.py file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#

import config
import os
import sys

# Force sys.path to have our own directory first, so we can import from it.
sys.path.insert(0, config.APP_ROOT_DIR)
sys.path.insert(1, os.path.join(config.APP_ROOT_DIR, 'externals'))
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "settings"


import wsgiref.handlers

from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.dist import use_library

use_library('django', '1.2')


from handlers import error, timer, do_openid_login


def main():

    application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', timer.ExportHandler),
        ('/_ah/login_required', do_openid_login.OpenIdLoginHandler),
        ('/player/([-\w]+)', timer.PlayerHandler),
        ('/player/([-\w]+)/archives', timer.ArchivesHandler),
        ('/stat/([-\w]+)', timer.StatHandler),
        ('/stat/([-\w]+)/delete', timer.StatDeleteHandler),                                          
        # If we make it this far then the page we are looking
        # for does not exist
        ('/.*', error.Error404Handler),
        ],
        debug=True)
    wsgiref.handlers.CGIHandler().run(application)


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Comment: Can you show the full traceback?

Comment: @DanCornilescu Added as a part of the original error.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, your `app.yaml` file might not be properly mapping your application code. You need to:

- take the `application` variable outside of the `main()` function so that it becomes a global variable in the `main.py` module (and maybe rename it to `app` as well - just to stay inline with the official convention and documentation examples)
- replace the `script: main.py` statements from your `app.yaml`'s `handlers` with `main.application` (or `main.app` if renamed as mentioned above) - this is the reference to the above-mentioned global variable. From the `script` row in the [Handlers element](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers_element) table:

> A **script**: directive must be a python import path, for example,
>   **package.module.app** that points to a WSGI application. The last component of a **script**: directive using a **Python module** path is
>   the name of a global variable in the module: that variable must be a
>   WSGI app, and is usually called **app** by convention.

I'd also recommend explicitly passing the `app.yaml` as argument to `dev_appserver.py` instead of the app's directory (`.` in your case) - occasionally the auto-detection doesn't behave as expected. It's also the only way to run multiple services and/or using a `dispatch.yaml` file for routing, so it's a good habit.